# Rails: Nil checking a method chain best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, try-catch, method-chaining

Given the following method. How best to make this code safe when the result of `comment.story.teams.first` could be `nil`?

I've tried `comment.story.teams.first.try(:users)` but then that kicks the can down the road and the assignment `users -= [@current_user]` throws an `undefined method` error.

```
  def recipients
    if comment.commentable_type == "Story"
      users = comment.story.teams.first.users
    else
      users = comment.other_commenters + [comment.commentable_user]
    end
    users -= [@current_user]
    users.uniq
  end
```

Is there a better pattern I could be using here?

Comment: In case you haven't thought of this (not trying to insult your intelligence):  ```(users || []) -= [@current_user]```  or do it earlier ```users = comment.story.teams.first.try(:users) || []```

Comment: Never insulted. Just confused about best practices when switching between languages as I often do. This works well. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap whatever you need to check in ruby's unless statement.

```
unless comment.story.teams.first.nil?
   ##Execute code in here
end
```

Hope that helps. Might be easier to restructure some of the statements in the method. 'Unless' is just ruby syntax for 'if not'.